# Addthis sharing padding/margins

Tags: css

I've added addthis share buttons to a page [here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/news/2013/November/festive-fun-coming-to-brentwood-in-the-next-month.html) and I can't get equal margins/distribution across the div width, so there's a gap on the right hand side which takes into account the fluid width.

I've tried proportional margins/paddings at different percentages, but can't seem to make it responsive.

Here's the CSS and the rest is viewable in an inspector:

```
.bg.social {
border: 1px solid #FCFCFD;
padding: 15px 0;
background: #E4E4E4;
text-align: center;
width: 94%;
margin: 0 0 2em;
height: 32px;
}

.bg.social a {
margin: 0 4%;
padding: 0;
float: none;
}

.addthis_toolbox {
margin: 0 2%;
}
```

Update: Got it to work with the following, the same as Bartdude's answer:

```
.bg.social a {
padding: 0 3%;
display: inline-block;
}

.bg.social {
border: 1px solid #FCFCFD;
padding: 15px 0;
background: #E4E4E4;
text-align: center;
width: 95%;
margin: 0 0 2em;
}
```

Comment: please create a jsFiddle instead of posting a link, which will soon not show your problem anymore, making your question of no use for anybody in the future. a piece of advice about your problem though, maybe have a look at inline-block display for your links, allowing the use of text-align AND margins around it.

Comment: Good point, will do in future. Tried inline-block, text-align and margins before and didn't work. Thanks though

Comment: If you want to answer @Bartdude, I'll accept yours as it's close. Thought you meant adding all those to the links, but see what you mean - the only other thing needed was to declare 'float:none' to '.bg.social a' to override the addthis css.

Comment: I've posted an answer with a bit more explanations than my comment. Glad it helped !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what you want is to be able to use `text-align:center` on your button links. Problem is you can't do that, as you floated them for them to appear side-by-side.

I would then suggest to change the display of those anchors to `display:inline-block` (be carefull though it's not supported by older IE versions... I don't find it important myself but maybe your target audience is using it), so that you can both make use of the `text-align:center` of the parent and still have a margin around each anchor.

Alternatively, I would suggest only putting a right or left margin, and use CSS pseudo classes `:last-child` or `:first-child` so that the first or last element don't have that margin. This shouldn't actually make no visible difference, but your CSS would be a bit more clean and modern...

Comment: This solution works. I didn't add any floats or CSS though as they came from the addthis javascript/css and needed overriding in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `margin` to

```
.addthis_toolbox {
     margin: 0 10%; // from 2 to 10%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.addthis_toolbox {
    margin: 0 5%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that breaks the links onto another line at < 1225px screen resolutions, taking into account '.bg.social a {margin: 0 4%;}'

Answer (score 0):

I cleared all the margins and divs in parent and child divs. Then :

```
.bg.social a { width:20% }// divided to 5 equal part
```

and dicreased the margin of .addthis_toolbox.addthis_32x32_style span {

```
.addthis_toolbox.addthis_32x32_style span {margin-left: 20px;}
```

everything is ok.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did try 15% equal widths before, taking into account extra margins and padding such as '.addthis_toolbox.addthis_32x32_style span {margin-left: 20px}'. The margins should all be percentages, but can't seem able to create equal width links together with percentage margins/padding, suitable for fluid widths

Answer (score 0):

Try it, add to your css:

```
div.foraddthis {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.addthis_toolbox {
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    display: inline-flex;
}
.addthis_default_style .at300b {
    float: none;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="foraddthis">
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style"> <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_share"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_share"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_tumblr"></a>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-529d1f4f354abd32"></script>
</div>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vPw7u/